# Unable to set a input field with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a onChange event that should trigger the update of an input field.  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select id="builds" onchange="setBuild()">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    ...
</select>


<input type="text" id="buildInfo" name="buildInfo" style="margin-top:10px;" value=""/>
```

ExtJS:

```
function setBuild(){

    var value = Ext.get("builds").dom.options[Ext.get("builds").dom.selectedIndex].text;

    Ext.get("buildInfo").update(value);
}
```

I've verified that I'm passing a valid value but I'm still unable to update the value for my input element.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Just a suggestion (hence a comment not an answer) but you may find this functionality easier to use in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Update method is typically used to replace inner html of the element. perhaps you can just set the value of the buildInfo element by Ext.get("buildInfo").value = value .

Honestly though I have never seen extjs used in this way :)

Comment: Well that's not ExtJS, that's Ext Core.

Answer (score 1):

For input field: Ext.get('binfo').dom.value = value